Datatable Yajra Laravel not working: pagination and search box
I need some help. The result is showing up, but the data table formatting isn't working—none of the buttons or search boxes are functioning.
Script
$(document).ready(function() {
      function initializeDataTable(numChave) {
          new DataTable('#datatable-basic' + numChave, {
              language: {
                  url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.13.7/i18n/pt-BR.json',
                  decimal: ',',
              },
              ajax: {
                  url: '{{ route("get.ops", ":num_chave") }}'.replace(':num_chave', numChave),
                  type: 'GET',
                  dataSrc: 'data'
              },
              columns: [
                  { data: 'COD_PRODUTO', name: 'COD_PRODUTO' }
              ],
              processing: true,
              serverSide: true,
              dom: 'Bfrtip',
              lengthMenu: [
                  [10, 25, 50, -1],
                  ['10 Linhas', '25 Linhas', '50 Linhas', 'Mostrar tudo']
              ],
              buttons: [
                  'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'pageLength'
              ],
              initComplete: function() {
                  this.api().columns().every(function() {
                      let column = this;
                      let title = column.footer().textContent;
  
                      // Create input element
                      let input = document.createElement('input');
                      input.placeholder = title;
                      column.footer().replaceChildren(input);
  
                      // Event listener for user input
                      input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
                          if (column.search() !== input.value) {
                              column.search(input.value).draw();
                          }
                      });
                  });
              }
          });
      }
  
      // Inicializar DataTables para cada tabela dinâmica
      @foreach ($mrpsOps as $op)
          initializeDataTable({{ $op->NUM_CHAVE }});
      @endforeach

Route
Route::get('/get-ops/{num_chave}', [MrpItemController::class, 'getOps'])->name('get.ops');

Controller
public function getOps($num_chave, Request $request) {
 $ops = DB::table('my_treqdevmats')
        ->where('NUM_CHAVEOP', $num_chave)
        ->select(['COD_PRODUTO', 'NUM_REQMATERIAL', 'QTD_REQUISITADA', 'DAT_CANCEL', 'FLG_CANCELADO'])
        ->get();

    
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $ops
    ]);
}

The information in the column is appearing correctly, but none of the buttons or the search box are working. I would like to know what is wrong with the script so that the datatable functions, such as pagination, filtering, and the search box, are not working.
